# Is it possible to generate actual RESTful web service using predefined interfaces?

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest, wsdl, interop

I am building an application in which I need to expose a service interface. The intent is to distribute service interface to other participating applications which will be creating actual web service using the service interface. Other applications may or may not be using .NET platform. My application will be a client to all those web service created (using interface I defined) and hosted by other applications.

For this, I defined service interface (`ServiceContract`s in `WCF` world) and created `WSDL` out of it. I'll be distributing WSDL to other applications which will generate actual web service on their platform.

1. In this case, can I use RESTful service? How beneficial will it be?
2. **In REST world, is it possible to define the service contracts (C# interfaces) and let other parties generate the actual web service?** (I read some blags about `WADL` but people are not recommending it!
3. Is it possible to migrate existing WCF service to REST?

I am new to REST world !

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to migrate your existing WCF service to a RESTful mode. I am currently engaged in a similar activity. The service that I am migrating only consists of reading data, so just a GET is involved here. For a PUT or POST some more work will be needed.

I am new to the REST world as well. I have an example that can be found [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ai924bnkct9j1lz/Lesson5.zip)